# Decomposition of Control-V gates using CNOT and single qubit gate?

Tags: quantum-gate, linear-algebra, quantum-control

In the book "Introduction to quantum algorithms via linear algebra", there is a problem 6.8, that said: "Show that CV can be written as a composition of (appropriate powers of) T gates before and after a controlled rotation CRx(θ). Deduce that CNOT is the only two-qubit gate needed to simulate CV"
I tried many cases but can't make it true. Does anyone know how to do that? Thanks!

Comment: Interestingly CV is equal to CRx(angle=pi/2)

Comment: @Callum Thank you. But i dont think it's true, what is your CRx matrix?

Comment: I'm using 


$
CRx =
\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & \cos(\theta/2) & -i\sin(\theta/2) \\
0 & 0 & -i\sin(\theta/2) &  \cos(\theta/2) 

\end{pmatrix}
$

Comment: Note that qiskit use the opposite qubit ordering convention meaning the unitary matrix looks different. It shouldn't really matter as long we are consistent with whatever qubit ordering convention we choose.
https://qiskit.org/documentation/stubs/qiskit.circuit.library.CRXGate.html